# Hadoop - Accumulo Will not Start From Ambari

Tags: apache, hadoop, accumulo

I am running Ambari Hadoop and the Accumulo services will not start.

Error Logs

Accumulo GC, Accumulo Monitor:
Python script has been killed due to timeout after waiting 600 secs

Is this a common error that people have had? If so what is the fix?

Thanks!

Comment: Other error message: Connection failed: [Errno 111] Connection refused to mfti-hdp-n01.local:12234

Comment: You should pull out more of the log messages from `/var/log/accumulo` for the GC and Monitor. There should be a log file for each service.

Comment: 2016-06-29 11:46:12,754 [fs.VolumeManagerImpl] WARN : dfs.datanode.synconclose set to false in hdfs-site.xml: data loss is possible on hard system reset or power loss
2016-06-29 11:46:12,757 [init.Initialize] INFO : Hadoop Filesystem is hdfs://mfti-hdp-n01.local:8020
2016-06-29 11:46:12,757 [init.Initialize] INFO : Accumulo data dirs are [hdfs://mfti-hdp-n01.local:8020/apps/accumulo/data]
2016-06-29 11:46:12,757 [init.Initialize] INFO : Zookeeper server is mfti-hdp-n03.local:2181,mfti-hdp-n02.local:2181,mfti-hdp-n01.local:2181
2016-06-29 11:46:12,757 [init.Initialize] INFO : Checking

Comment: Not much info there. Is this the first time you've started Accumulo? I would check if its created any accumulo directories on HDFS, if not its probably having trouble talking to the namenode perhaps.

Comment: This is my first time starting Accumulo and only the second time I've installed Hadoop on a cluster so apologies for my vague questions. A better question may be is Accumulo necessary for regular operation of Hadoop?

Comment: No, it runs on top of Hadoop and you only need it if you're going use it. It provides a key/value store similar to HBase.

Comment: not sure if this helps, but here is what I get when I try to access the /apps/accumulo directory in HDFS: [root@mfti-hdp-n01 accumulo]# hadoop fs -ls /apps/accumulo
ls: Permission denied: user=root, access=READ_EXECUTE, inode="/apps/accumulo":accumulo:hdfs:drwx------